# Mixing enums with event classes in an event aggregator

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, eventaggregator

I attempted to implement my own simple event aggregator recently. I got a lot of inspiration from the event aggregator article on MSDN. There is one thing that I notice about the event aggregator on MSDN is the events are actually classes on their own. This isn't really a bad thing at all. However, I just find it awkward to always create a new empty class for every single little event.

The reason I find it awkward is because of the need to create a class for every single granular event. A mouse click event, for instance, would have double_click, single_click, left_click, right_click, etc. And all of these are going to have a class of its own. It gets messy after a while.

So in my own implementation, I thought I could make it in such a way where the `ClickEvent` is a class, but all the granular events related to the Click event would then be "types" of the `ClickEvent`. In this case, the "types" are `enum`. The usage would look something like this:

```
//Publisher
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ClickEvent>.Publish(ClickEventType.Double_Click, eventArgs);

//Subscriber
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ClickEvent>.Subscribe(ClickEventType.Double_Click, handlerMethod);
```

However, I'm not sure if this implementation defeats the whole purpose of having a strongly typed event? Now, it seems like the `ClickEvent` is merely a container for the different event enum types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does (seem like a container that is) - your handler will fire regardless of the click type and there will be some code required in the handler to determine the type of click, which makes things a little messier.

If your issue is mostly the organisation of the files/classes and keeping the code tidy, why not just create the click events as nested classes within a main click class

e.g.

```
public static class ClickEvents // Prevent instantiation
{
    public class SingleLeft { }
    public class SingleRight { }
    public class DoubleLeft { }
    public class DoubleRight { }
    // Are there any more click events possible?!
}

eventAggregator.GetEvent<ClickEvents.SingleLeft>.Publish();
```

Aside from that, it's the uniqueness of the type that determines the event signature, and therefore multiple types are required to satisfy this particular implementation

At least the above keeps your handler code clean

```
void HandleLeftClick()
{
}
```

vs

```
void HandleClick(ClickArgs e) 
{
    if(e.ClickType == ClickType.Left)
    {
    }
}
```

Edit:

Also remember that you can subscribe multiple events to the same handler if you want to handle more than one click type:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ClickEvents.SingleLeft>.Subscribe(HandlerMethod);
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ClickEvents.SingleRight>.Subscribe(HandlerMethod);
```

(this would work in the rare situation that the subscriber didn't care which mouse button was clicked)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed one possibility. You see, you don't have to create a new class for each notification. Instead, you are free to reuse classes but carry some additional state of arbitrary complexity inside.

```
public class MouseClickNotification {

    public bool IsDoubleClick;
    public MouseButton ClickedButton;

    // any additional stuff
```

This way it is you who precisely define the granularity of your notification model.

Comment: That works assuming you want some code in the handler to determine what type of click was raised. This works fine if you are prepared to keep writing that code in each handler - it's whichever the lesser of two evils is for you I suppose

Comment: This works always. What I mean is not to suggest any specific model behind mouse events but to show that thinking like "let us have a new class for everything" leads nowhere. Note his idea of having classes for single click, double click, left click and right click. How is he supposed to model left double clicks and right double clicks this way?

Comment: Just create a class for each one of those particular events - e.g. SingleLeft, DoubleLeft. I'm not saying your implementation is wrong, it would seem like the natural thing to do, but obviously, you end up with a little extra code in every single click handler to determine which type of click it was, whereas creating a type for each event message gives you the freedom of knowing what event type was inbound without doing additional processing in the handler. Whichever one makes life easier for you, I just prefer the type-per-message implementation.

Comment: I didn't answer the last bit - for a 'Click' event (where the user doesn't care which button was clicked)...well I think these situations are quite rare (it's not often that it doesn't matter which button was clicked!) but if that is the case, then the subscriber can subscribe to both the `SingleLeft` and `SingleRight` click events. This would fire the same handler regardless of what was clicked so you still have a simpler implementation. In my opinion it's up to the subscription to decide what events should fire the handler. It's not the handlers responsibility to filter events.

Comment: Well, the base class library suggests models to handle mouse click information, the MouseEventArgs class from System.Windows.Forms, for example. A single notification type, filtered at the client side. Are there any examples of a model similar to yours somewhere out there?

Comment: Probably (e.g. I can't give you any examples outside my own code), but just because Microsoft are doing it with `EventArgs`, doesn't mean it needs to be used for every other subscription based pattern. The implementation provided on MSDN does provide a filter delegate which allows you to filter messages based on message content before the handler is called, so that's the better alternative. Like I said, it's just a subtlety